# Calculate hash of an h2o frame

Tags: python, r, h2o

I would like to calculate some hash value of an `h2o.frame.H2OFrame`. Ideally, in both `R` and `python`. My understanding of `h2o.frame.H2OFrame` is that these objects basically "live" on the `h2o` server (i.e., are represented by some `Java` objects) and not within `R` or `python` from where they might have been uploaded.

I want to calculate the hash value "as close as possible" to the actual training algorithm. That rules out calculation of the hash value on (serializations of) the underlying `R` or `python` objects, as well as on any underlying files from where the data was loaded.
The reason for this is that I want to capture all (possible) changes that `h2o`'s upload functions perform on the underlying data.

Inferring from the [h2o docs](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/9/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/frame.html), there is no hash-like functionality exposed through `h2o.frame.H2OFrame`.
One possibility to achieve a hash-like summary of the `h2o` data is through summing over all numerical columns and doing something similar for categorical columns. However, I would really like to have some avalanche effect in my hash function so that small changes in the function input result in large differences of the output. This requirement rules out simple sums and the like.

Is there already some interface which I might have overlooked?
If not, how could I achieve the task described above?

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
iris_df=h2o.upload_file(path="~/iris.csv")

# what I would like to achieve
iris_df.hash()
# >>> ab2132nfqf3rf37 

# ab2132nfqf3rf37 is the (made up) hash value of iris_df
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if i remember correctly, there is already something like that calculated on the java side.  i think it was used in the back-end in part to keep track of whether the rollupstats like min/max/mean have already been calculated for a frame.  you might find it if you look at the rest api json response by hand.

Comment: I have now looked at the REST API responses of both `ImportFiles` and `PostFile`/`ParseSetup`. None of these include anything hash-like.

Comment: BTW: I looked at it via the flow web interface and Chrome developer tools.

Comment: We do expose checksum field which seems like what you are looking for: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/api/schemas3/FrameV3.java#L47

This is returned in the REST API.

Comment: @TomKraljevic Sorry, was probably misunderstanding your comment and thought I would get back a json (with the checksum) directly as a response to `ImportFiles` or `PostFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available in the REST API [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwiR4.png) (see screenshot) you can probably get to it in the H2OFrame object in Python as well but it is not directly exposed.

Answer (score 1):

So here a complete solution in `python` based on Michal Kurka's and Tom Kraljevic's suggestions:

```
import h2o
import requests
import json

h2o.init()

iris_df = h2o.upload_file(path="~/iris.csv")

apiEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/Frames/"
res = json.loads(requests.get(apiEndpoint + iris_df.frame_id).text)

print("Checksum 1: ", res["frames"][0]["checksum"])

#change a bit
iris_df[0, 1] = iris_df[0, 1] + 1e-3

res = json.loads(requests.get(apiEndpoint + iris_df.frame_id).text)

print("Checksum 2: ", res["frames"][0]["checksum"])

h2o.cluster().shutdown()
```

This gives

```
Checksum 1:  8858396055714143663
Checksum 2:  -4953793257165767052
```

Thanks for your help!